# JQuery Validating Multiple Checkbox Groups

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have the following two checkbox groups:

```
<fieldset class="CbxGroup">
  <legend>Checkbox Group (required)</legend>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1[]" value="one" id="cbxGroup1_0">One </label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1[]" value="two" id="cbxGroup1_1">Two </label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1[]" value="three" id="cbxGroup1_2">Three</label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1[]" value="four" id="cbxGroup1_3">Four </label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1[]" value="five" id="cbxGroup1_4">Five </label>
  <br>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="CbxGroup">
<legend>Checkbox Group (required)</legend>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup2[]" value="one" id="cbxGroup2_0">One </label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup2[]" value="two" id="cbxGroup2_1">Two </label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup2[]" value="three" id="cbxGroup2_2">Three</label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup2[]" value="four" id="cbxGroup2_3">Four </label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup2[]" value="five" id="cbxGroup_4">Five </label>
  <br>
</fieldset>
```

Each checkbox-group (fieldset) is tagged with the same class name. I'd like to validate each GROUP so at least one checkbox is selected in EACH group.

I have the following JQuery but it sees them as a single group rather than two separate ones. Can you help me tweak this code so it validates each group separately?

```
$('.CbxGroup').each(function() {
        if($('.CbxGroup input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
            alert('not selected!');
        }
        else{
            alert('selected!');
        }
    });
```

This way I can add any number of checkbox-groups and have them all validated rather writing separate chunks of code for each group.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to change the selector for the length check:

```
$('.CbxGroup').each(function() { 
    if($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) { 
        alert('not selected!'); 
    } 
    else{ 
        alert('selected!'); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$('.CbxGroup').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(':checked').length == 0) {
        alert('not selected!');
    }
    else{
        alert('selected!');
    }
});
```